# Need to redirect all subdomains from old URL to subdomains on new URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have migrated a website, and now having issues with users that have saved certain pages and pdfs as bookmarks and are now getting broken link errors. I need the links to go to the same areas on the new site.

I assume it will be some type of code needed to be added to the .htaccess.

Here is an example:

Old URL: "www.oldsite.co.nz/things/stuff/thisisapdf.pdf"
Needs to go to
New URL: "www.newsite.co.nz/files/thisisapdf.pdf"

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways you can go about this using plugins.

1) https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
- This is great when migrating or moving sites, as it automatically can repoint the urls for you when you reupload.

or 2) https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
- This will allow you to change the urls on a case by case basis. This is recommended if you don't have too many broken links.

Comment: Hi Levi. The problem is not broken links on the new website. The problem is users having bookmarked old page links to the old site. And now they get an error when visiting those links. I want them to be redirected to the new location on the new site of the same files

Comment: In that case, I would try to use the redirection plugin. I have migrated sites before, and with this plugin you can see which urls are returning 500 server errors for you user. Then, you can just change the url to point to the new destination